# Como fazer um algoritmo para transformar maiúsculas em minúsculas?

Tags: algoritmo, portugol

Necessito de uma algoritmo que aceite uma string ou expressão literal em caixa alta ou uppercase ou lowercase. Exemplo:

```
leia(nome)
```

Independente da entrada:

> Fulano, FULano, fulano ou FULANO

A saída do código `escreva(nome)` dever ser:

> fulano

Comment: Legal. E o que você fez até agora?

Comment: se (estadoCivil="casado") ou (estadoCivil="CASADO")

Comment: Mas como isso se relaciona com sua pergunta?

Comment: quero uma forma que independente da entrada : Casado, CASADO, casado, CaSaDo a saida seja casado. O algoritmo reconheca a entrada como valida.

Comment: +1 pela pergunta, legal o questionamento com relação ao uso do portugol^^

Comment: @alexjosesilva seus comentários me deixaram um pouco confuso, você quer apenas converter para tudo minúsculo ou quer validar se o que foi digitado é ou não minúsculo?

Comment: Obrigado pela respota Math. Quero os dois: Validar uma condicional e converter qualquer entrada para minusculo. Grato pelo ajuda

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O Portugol tem uma função que trata isso, é a função `caracteres_minusculos`.

Da documentação (que se encontra dentro do próprio software):

> Biblioteca Texto
>   `funcao cadeia caracteres_minusculos(cadeia cad)`
>
> Descrição: Transforma os caracteres de uma cadeia em caracteres minúsculos
>
> Parâmetros:
>   cad: um valor qualquer do tipo cadeia
>   Retorna: a cadeia com os caracteres transformados

Lembre-se de importar a biblioteca `Texto` para poder usar a função de conversão dos caracteres corretamente.

Exemplo completo:

```
programa
{
    inclua biblioteca Texto --> txt
    funcao inicio()
    {
        cadeia texto
        leia(texto)
        escreva("Texto convertido para minúsculo: ", txt.caracteres_minusculos(texto) )
    }
}
```

Comment: Estou usando o Visualg, como seria esta inclusção. Lembrando que meu codigo esta assim:algoritmo "REPETIÇÃO"

var
   I:inteiro
inicio

   // Repetição
   PARA  I DE 0 ATE 20 FACA
    ESCREVAL(" ",I)
   FIMPARA

fimalgoritmo

Comment: @alexjosesilva o que é o Visualg? É um outro nome para o Portugol? De qualquer forma, não seria o caso de ser uma pergunta separada?

Comment: Visualg é a IDE para fazer leitura de algoritmos. A resposta acima esta um pouco confusa!

Comment: @alexjosesilva entendi, se trata de outra IDE, similar ao Portugol. A resposta acima apenas transforma todos os caracteres para minúsculos de um texto qualquer digitado pelo usuário, sugiro que você rode o código acima e faça um teste. Você havia dito que quer fazer uma validação de alguma condição, mas até agora não entendi qual, poderia me explicar?